# React Native - Async/Await on Class not working as expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Here is my code...

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AsyncStorage
} = React;



exports.buildUrl = function(){
  var test = new Sales();
  test.getOrder();
}

class queryBuilder{

  constructor() {

  }

  getUrl(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('auth').then((value) => {
      var auth = JSON.parse(value);
      var store = auth.url;
      console.log('store = ' + store);
      return store;
    });
  }

}

class Sales extends queryBuilder{

  async getOrder(){
    console.log('get order hit');
    try{
        var urlstart =  await this.getUrl();
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('ERROR')
      console.log(e);
    }
    console.log('URL BELOW');
    console.log(urlstart);
    console.log('URL ABOVE');
  }

}
```

In my `getOrder` method I was hoping that `urlstart` would not be `undefined` because i have used await.

The `console.log` within `getUrl()` method is the last thing to return in my console.

Maybe it's that saturday feeling, any help much appreciated!

Comment: Why not make it a simple `async getUrl() { return JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth')).url; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Resovled this myself. `Async` `Await` require a promise to be returned on the function i'm calling.
I have modified the `getUrl()` method like below..

```
  getUrl(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('auth').then((value) => {
        var auth = JSON.parse(value);
        var store = auth.url;
        console.log('store = ' + store);
        resolve(store);
      });
    }
```

Any further sugestions still greatly appreciated.

Updated better, Thanks to Yuri

```
getUrl(){ return AsyncStorage.getItem('auth').then(value => JSON.parse(value).url) }
```

Comment: `getUrl(){
    return AsyncStorage.getItem('auth').then(value => JSON.parse(value).url)
    }` should be enough

Comment: Show just the `function` itself just needs to return, i just had the wrong scope?

Comment: Since you allready have a promise you don't need to create one manually. Simple return would suffice.

Comment: Please update your answer, using `new Promise` in this case is an antipattern.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: What do you mean anti pattern ? Promise in promise?

Comment: You should do `return AsyncStorage.getItem('auth').then((value) => { ... return store;});`. Don't create a new promise if you already have one.